# Add MyMaps map to an Android Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, mymaps

I'm currently working on a project where I need to add a Google **My Maps** map to a fragment, but I've been searching for a while, and I haven't been able to find a way to introduce the URL. My guess is that it should be a method somewhere in the GoogleMap class.
Also, I have noticed that there are some methods like addPolygon which could help achieve a similar result as the MyMaps map. However, that would be a pretty messy approach, as I'd have to add many coordinates, and it would become really time consuming.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im not sure about process of not saving the KML file and showing in `Fragment`.

> But by manually downloading the file as shown below , we can include
>   the same in Fragment.

---

[image]

Now create folder `raw` inside `res` folder.

Paste the downloaded `KML` file in `raw` folder.

Update the dependency of google maps as shown.

```
api 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
```

Inside your fragment do the following.

```
KmlLayer kmlFile;

public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
   ...............
   ...............
   try {
            kmlFile = new KmlLayer(googleMap, R.raw.my_map, getContext());
            kmlFile.addLayerToMap();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,""+e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,""+e.toString());
        }
}
```

I have used below to display normal google map. This map loading is as usual procedure for showing map in Fragment

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/placeOrderMap"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
>
</com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>
```

Now once the Fragment is loaded, swipe to the location were you created your Google My Maps and you can see the created map Pin / Icon etc.

The output will be as shown below according to your created elements.

[image]

Comment: Hello, your method seems to work pretty fine when exporting to a KML. If instead I use the KMZ version, in order to keep the icons, I get an error from the XmlParser: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unterminated entity ref (position:TEXT @1:213 in java.io.InputStreamReader@df5ffa7) . If I extract the KML from the generated KMZ, it works, but without the icons' images, of course. Any idea if I need to use something special for kmz?

Comment: I have no clue on those lines. Probably you can post this specific question as a different thread. As its more specific than your question **Add MyMaps map to an Android Fragment**

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `GoogleMap` object for My Maps visualization. Just add `WebView` to your fragment and load your My Map into it via shared URL:

```
private WebView mMyMapWebView;
...

mMyMapWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mymap_webview);
mMyMapWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mMyMapWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
mMyMapWebView.loadUrl(<your_mymap__url_e.g. https://drive.google.com/open?id=...>);
```

in `.xml` `WebView` can be described like that:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/mymap_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>
```

Sharing URL for your My Map you can get by press Share button on My Maps control panel:

[image: My Maps Main view]

and in on window with shared URL you also should change access rights from private to "Anyone who has link" or public:

[image: My Maps Sharing settings]

and than, on Android device you get something like that:

[image: My Maps on Android device]